# How to solve Type 'MyType' does not conform to multiple protocols?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to swift and I dont understand what these errors mean, wondering if anyone can suggest how to fix these, thanks in advance.

```
struct Place: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {



    var placeName: String
    var regularEvents:[WeeklyEvent]


}
```

I get the error type 'Place' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes because of this `var weeklyEvents:[WeeklyEvent]
You need to define`WeeklyEvent` struct

```
struct WeeklyEvent: Codable, Hashable {
//your properties

}
```

Comment: Yes @TylerTheCompiler